# Type of iterator erroneous

Tags: java

I am working on a project in java and I am developing a API for custom  components. I am using an interface called `DrawHandler` to allow the components to draw to a graphics object. To do this every time a component is added I need to add it's `DrawHandler`s to a list. I am using this code

```
    public void addComponent(Component c){
         //Add to list of components
         components.add(c);
         //Add all of the components drawHandlers so the component can be drawn
         List<DrawHandler> dhs = c.getDrawHandlers();
         Iterator<DrawHandler> i = dhs.iterator();
         while(i.hasNext()){
            addDrawHandler(i.next());
         }
    }
```

However when I get an error on this line

```
 Iterator<DrawHandler> i = dhs.iterator();
```

and this line

```
addDrawHandler(i.next())
```

The error is:

> The type of next() is erroneous :    where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in interface Iterator

If I use this code as sugested

```
    public void addComponent(Component c){
    //Add to list of components
    components.add(c);
    //Add all of the components drawHandlers so the component can be drawn
    for(DrawHandler handler : c.getDrawHandlers())
        addDrawHandler(handler);
}
```

I get this error when i compile it : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: windows.DrawHandler
    at windows.MainWin.addComponent(MainWin.java:37)
    at windows.Main.main(MazeNavigator.java:21)
Any sugjestions? What am I doing wrong? thanks for your your help

Comment: Surely you don't get that error on both lines?

Comment: Please post your whole class.

Comment: You do have the `import` line for `DrawHandler`, right?

Comment: Yes I have imported it

Comment: I am going to vote for closing the question: as @SotiriosDelimanolis has already asked you to post the code of the class especially implementation of `addDrawHandler` function: you are not giving any attention to that. As the question currently stays- *it is completely unclear*. Please, edit the question as is being suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't explain your error but you may find it compiles fine if you write

```
for(DrawHandler handler : c.getDrawHandlers())
    addDrawHandler(handler);
```

> Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: windows.DrawHandler

This means you are using an option which allows you to run code which doesn't compile.  I suggest you turn this option off and you should see the true cause of your error.

Comment: I tried your sugestion and When I run it I get this error - Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: windows.DrawHandler

Comment: Now I get this error which sends me to a bunch of XML files I have never touched
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\windows\nbproject\build-impl.xml:902: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\windows\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1418: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GraphicsEngine\nbproject\build-impl.xml:896: Could not create C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\windows\build\built-jar.properties
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: @user2277362 this is telling you the BUILD FAILED, most likely due to a previous compilation error.  I suggest you look for that error.

Comment: I feel so stupid, I forgott to import DrawHandler... Check script before replying next time..... ):

Comment: You shouldn't need to check.  IMHO Your IDE should highlight that the class hasn't been imported and offer to do it for you. This is what IntelliJ does.